# Is this spam or just not an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, spam

This [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/18361/594) (the link is for 10k users) puzzles me: I first flagged it as *not an answer* but then looking at the [user profile](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/4705/patrick), I saw that just the website is filled (but without a correct link), so I reflagged it as *spam*.

How should this be considered?

The answer text is the following one:

> aaaaah that is how you do it on a Mac!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-sense post without any link is not spam; it is spam if it contains links that don't have any purpose, if not promoting something.

If a user keep adding the link for a library in any posted answer, saying "This [library](http://example.com/library_name) can help you." on Stack Overflow those answers would be flagged as spam. If a user just writes "Me too!" as answer, that user is not considered spammer. I don't buy the assumption that the user wrote a non-sense comment to let me check his user profile, and follow a spam link. When I see a non-sense post, I just flag it; I don't look at the user profile.

That answer should rather be a comment, but it doesn't make sense as comment too.

Comment: *it doesn't make sense as comment too*, that's exactly why I thought this could be spam, sometimes spamers post comment that are very broad like *this was useful* and don't even include a link in it but their profile has it.

Comment: Thanks for the precision.